# Хотите ли вы использовать Traducir.win для перевода интерфейса сайта?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Интерфейс движка вопросов и ответов Stack Exchange переводится на русский язык участниками русскоязычных сообществ. Чтобы коллективный перевод стал возможным, мы используем сервис [Transifex.com](https://www.transifex.com/). Transifex — отличный сайт. Но не идеальный. Текущая интеграция движка SE с Transifex порождает серьезную проблему — теряется перевод строк при исправлении опечаток в англоязычной версии. Кроме того, есть несколько критичных замечаний:

- *Необходима учетная запись на Transifex*. Переводчикам необходимо иметь учетную запись на Transifex.com, которая не связана с учетной записью на Stack Exchange.
- *Нет нужных уведомлений*. Например, что был подтвержден перевод, появилось новое предложение, настала пора обновлять базу переводов движка.

От этих и другим проблем страдало не только русскоязычное сообщество, но и все остальные международные сайты… Пока ребята из Stack Overflow на испанском не сделали приложение [Traducir.win](https://traducir.win/), которое решает часть проблем.

Кратко о Traducir.win:

- Приложение с открытым исходным кодом, написано на .NET, доступно на [GitHub](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir). Работает поверх Transifex API (то есть это надстройка над Transifex, а не отдельный сайт). Любой желающий может улучшить сервис или предложить улучшение.
- Для авторизации используется учетная запись Stack Overflow. Модераторы по умолчанию имеют права на подтверждение строк. Они же могут выдать (или забирать) аналогичные права другим участникам.
- Приложение сохраняет переводы в своей базе. В случае «потери» перевода на Transifex, Traducir.win попытается его восстановить.
- Есть возможность отметить конкретную строку срочной для перевода.
- Есть пуш–уведомления для обозревателей о новых строка для подтверждения, о новых предложениях перевода, о появлении строк, отмеченных срочными, а также о необходимости обновить базу строк.
- Есть список участников–переводчиков, можно посмотреть их вклад.
- Строки для перевода можно искать регулярным выражением.

На мой взгляд, эти улучшения могут заметно упростить перевод сайта и дать возможность принять участие в улучшении интерфейса большему кругу участников.

- [Краткое демо видео (на англ языке)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbpoWXctN3Y).

Вопрос к сообществу:

> *Подскажите, хотите ли вы перейти с Transifex на Traducir.win для работы над переводами интерфейса сайта?*

Сейчас Traducir.win используется на Stack Overflow на испанскоим и на японском языках. Следует заметить, что если мы переходим на Traducir.win, то переводить через Transifex будет невозможно, так как Traducir.win будет «переписывать» добавленный вами вариант, на содержащийся в его базе.

Буду рад услышать ваш отзыв!

Comment: Там есть возможность обсуждать предложенные варианты перевода?

Comment: Синдром NIH в действии!

Comment: Но вообще я знаю, сколько стоят услуги Transifex (овердофига), так что это вполне может быть хорошим решением.

Comment: «теряется перевод строк при исправлении опечаток в англоязычной версии» — это нормальное поведение, так устроены инструменты для интернационализации приложений. Угадывать и подставлять перевод — ненадёжное решение, потому что догадка может быть неверной, и потому что так переводчики дольше не узнают об изменении перевода.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но можно же как-то иметь отдельный список "ресурсов вышедших из применения", чтобы не терять сами переводы. Какую-то корзину, очищающуюся раз в месяц, например.

Comment: @АндрейNOP назвается «память переводов», «translation memory». В Транзифексе была, в новом инструменте — не знаю, наверное тоже есть.

Comment: @АндрейNOP обсуждения переводов остаются на Мете. Как и глоссарий.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не могли бы опубликовать ответ с вашими мыслями на тему?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на чьей мете? РЯ часто меняет переводы, не спрашивая ruSO и наоборот.

Comment: Исторически, вся информация о переводе на русский язык хранится на MSOru.

Comment: hi folks! sorry that I'm using English, but I speak 0 words of Russian. If a string is changed on the source code, the string is reverted back to English (even with Traducir). This is because (as @NickVolynkin mentioned) it's the way the system is built. You can think about the system as a dictionary from English -> Russian. If the English version changes, then there's a new key without a translation.

Comment: What Traducir fixes is a bug that SO has with its integration with Transifex. From time to time, SO will delete strings from Transifex. Eventually, it will add them back, but when that happens, the string appears as "unreviewed" making really hard to know what's translated and what isn't.

Comment: А может основному SO как-то начать взаимодействовать с аборигенными xSO'ами (иксосы, жуть :)). Я имею в виду пустить нас в свой репозиторий чтобы вместе планировать изменения/исправления и править эти тексты на всех языках сразу. Просто по описанию, выглядит как будто, английский текст спускается из облаков в лучах света под хоровое пение, а мы тут должны его переложить на аборигенный язык.

Comment: @Cerbo Я разделяю ваше негодование о том, что русский язык сегодня не является самым распространенным на Земле (к слову, наличие таких проектов как Stack Overflow на русском улучшает ситуацию — позволяет накапливать больше знаний на родном языке). При этом, я не считаю себя «аборигеном». Не уверен, на сколько это сравнение нравится остальным. С другой стороны, система переводов работает таким образом, что есть исходный язык, а есть языки переводы. Для нашего сайта исходным является английский. Не более.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, слово "абориген" имеет значение "коренной житель страны" и ничего обидного в нем нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP Отлично!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А я не негодую, тем более по такому поводу. Наверно действительно переборщил с нагнетанием и не точно выразил что хотел, извините. Я хотел сказать, что по описанию выглядит, как-будто тексты пишутся без согласования на английском, а потом спускаются для перевода. Когда было бы разумнее и, не знаю, по-человечески писать их всем вместе.

Comment: @g3rv4, is it possibly use as key not a raw english string, but some key?

Comment: @Grundy we do have the transifex key (that's an alpha numeric key)... what did you have in mind? what would you like to see used as key?

Comment: @g3rv4, i thought, that as key used english string, so when it changed, transation break, because for new key no translation, but if you use some key, not depended on raw english string, then on change english should not loss transation, because in this case key not changed.

Comment: @Grundy that means rewriting all the views and all our js files, and rewriting the translation engine. Also means converting all the translations that are already in place to this new system. I can confidently say that it's a big endeavor and very unlikely to happen.

Comment: @g3rv4, well, no one said that it would be easy. :-D

Comment: @Grundy if you really wanted to have it considered, you could do a post at meta.SE... but IMO, you can easily find more productive things to do with your time ;)

Comment: @g3rv4, that's why i'm not translator :)