# Мы переносим Traducir на внутреннюю инфраструктуру компании

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, traducir, объявления

Прошло много времени с тех пор, как мы [начали использовать Traducir on Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8188/6) в 2018 году. Traducir запускался как проект с открытым исходным кодом, что позволило всем желающим принять участие в разработке и обсуждении проблем, с которыми мы сталкивались на пути. Traducir — это инструмент созданный для  международных сообществ самими международными сообществами.

Основную работу по разработке сервиса мы проделали в 2018 году. Единственная серьезная задача с тех пор была отказ от React (как выяснилось, его довольно сложно поддерживать). Кажется, что сервис отлично выполняет свою задачу на всех международных сайтах сети.

[image: График коммитов в Traducir на GitHub]

Глядя на график график выше — я горжусь тем, что мы создали что-то, что работает и требует минимального обслуживания.

С момента создания Traducir он работает на моей личной инфраструктуре, что не вызывало особого беспокойства, так как управляющие сообществами вручную проверяли все предложенные переводы, прежде чем они отправлялись на сайты. Сейчас некоторые процессы стали автоматизированным, что поднимает вопросы об отказоустойчивости сервиса.

Когда я впервые покинул Stack Overflow, я передал права на домен traducir.win компании Stack Overflow, но сервис продолжал работать в моей личной инфраструктуре. Теперь, когда я снова покидаю Stack Overflow (в конце этого месяца), я хотел бы снять с себя ответственность по поддержке самого сайта. Как результат, мы планируем перенести Traducir на инфраструктуру Stack Overflow, где компания будет обеспечивать его работу, безопасность и поддерживать его.

В рамках миграции мы планируем:

1. Сделать ответвление [текущего репозиторий Traducir](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir) в закрытый репозиторий компании.
2. Архивировать текущий публичный репозиторий (чтобы на код по-прежнему можно было ссылаться, но было ясно, что общедоступный репозиторий больше не поддерживается)
3. Перенести сам сервис на инфраструктуру компании.

Это означает, что участники международных сообществ больше не смогут отправлять запросы для устранения дефектов. Кажется, что это не должно стать проблемой: из истории коммитов видно, что последнее предложение от сообщества датируется 2019 годом (и даже это был бывший сотрудник).

Миграция никак не повлияет на людей, которые используют Traducir для отправки переводов, за исключением нескольких минут простоя сайта во время переноса сервиса на инфраструктуру компании. Мы просто хотим, чтобы вы все были в курсе происходящего.

Кажется, это все! Я рад передать Traducir Stack Overflow. :) Если у вас есть вопросы или пожелания, пожалуйста, опубликуйте их в этом вопросе. И если вы столкнетесь с какими-либо проблемами с Traducir (или захотите предложить улучшения), вы всегда можете опубликовать их на Мете (а модераторы сайта могут [довести их до сведения персонала](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/238921) при необходимости).

Этот же анонс на MSE: [We’re moving Traducir to our internal infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400/339911)

П.С. Спасибо [Николаю](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) за перевод этой публикации.

Comment: т.е. можно ожидать, что некоторые переводы опять слетят?...

Comment: Я ожидаю, что все будет работать так же, как и сейчас :)